# Is Robot framework compatible with Windows 10 OS (IE version -> 11.665.16299.0)

Tags: internet-explorer, robotframework

RF Scripts developed in windows 7 + IE 11.0.9600 fails during "**button click actions"**, while executing in windows 10 + IE 11.665.16299.0

Comment: In order to help you better it is best to provide as much information as possible. For example an [mcve] of the problem at hand. Also any information on your pyhton installation is virtually essential. I.e. versions for both systems of Python, Robot Framework and any external library used (ex. Selenium, PyAutoGU, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, robot framework is compatible with windows 10. It is compatible with any system that is capable of running modern versions of python.